# visualizing gazebo model in rviz

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

Is that possible to visualize the kitchen model which original from gazebo model library in Rviz? Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217324/visualizing--gazebo-model-in-rviz/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2015-09-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dinl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23729/dinl/) on 2015-09-12**:
One question about, how could you import the color into gazebo? I have a .obj file model with textures defined in .mtl file, then I convert it into .dae collada file, but gazebo doesn't load the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it is. The kitchen model is a single .dae (COLLADA) file that is available [here in the gazebo_models repo](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/b237ea45262f51ff8d72aaa96ef19f1288723c42/kitchen_dining/?at=default).

The easiest way to use it in rviz is probably to copy the model into a ROS package and then publish it as a [rviz Marker](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker) by using the [Mesh_Resource](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Mesh_Resource_.28MESH_RESOURCE.3D10.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D) approach.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might also be interested in the [gazebo2rviz](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo2rviz) package (sources [here](https://github.com/andreasBihlmaier/gazebo2rviz)). From the wiki page:

> This package contains nodes to automatically import all entities simulated in a ROS-enabled Gazebo instance into rviz through the TF and Marker plugin.

A related blog post on the author's site can be found [here](http://andreasbihlmaier.github.io/2014/02/19/gazebo2rviz.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2